# Jenkins/Maven checkstyle:check in pom.xml doesnt work

Tags: maven, jenkins, pom.xml, checkstyle

i have written the following pom.xml file, which should create a checkstyle report/tend graph and abort the build preocess if there are some checkstyle warnings.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>test</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <reporting>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
        <reportSets>
            <reportSet>
              <reports>
                <report>checkstyle</report>
              </reports>
            </reportSet>
          </reportSets>
          <configuration>
            <configLocation>https://dustplanet.de/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
  <build>
     <pluginManagement> 
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.17</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>validate</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>check</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                     <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                     <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                    <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
         </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
      </pluginManagement> 
       <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>   
    </build>

</project>
```

The problem is, if i build the maven project with jenkins and this maven goals `clean install` the project gets builded but the checkstyle plugin doesn't get executed. So i used `clean install site`. With `site` a report and a tend graph have been created but the build process still doesn't stop. After that i used `clean install site checkstyle:check -Dcheckstyle.config.location="https://dustplanet.de/checkstyle.xml"`, that way my build process failed, but the analysis result as well as the tend graph don't show any checkstyle error, although a report has been created in the target directory and the checkbox for always doing the analysis in the configuration of the job is activated. This is the console output of the last build:

```
Started by timer
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MavenProject2
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url git@essgitlab.fzi.de:SysKit/SYSKIT.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@essgitlab.fzi.de:SysKit/SYSKIT.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress git@essgitlab.fzi.de:SysKit/SYSKIT.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* +refs/merge-requests/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/merge-requests/*
 > git rev-parse origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 11d0f4105661346b7577fa223fe0f4063572fb99 (origin/master)
Commit message: "test"
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 11d0f4105661346b7577fa223fe0f4063572fb99
 > git rev-list 11d0f4105661346b7577fa223fe0f4063572fb99 # timeout=10
Parsing POMs
Established TCP socket on 35703
[test] $ java -cp /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven33-agent-1.11.jar:/opt/maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:/opt/maven/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven33Main /opt/maven /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-3.7.jar /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven33-interceptor-1.11.jar /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.11.jar 35703
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MavenProject2/test/pom.xml site clean install checkstyle:check -Dcheckstyle.config.location=https://dustplanet.de/checkstyle.xml
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building test 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-site-plugin:3.3:site (default-site) @ test ---
[INFO] configuring report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.8
[INFO] configuring report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Relativizing decoration links with respect to project URL: http://maven.apache.org
[INFO] Rendering site with org.apache.maven.skins:maven-default-skin:jar:1.0 skin.
[INFO] Generating "Checkstyle" report    --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.8
[INFO] 
[INFO] There are 1 checkstyle errors.
[WARNING] Unable to locate Source XRef to link to - DISABLED
[INFO] Generating "About" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Plugin Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Distribution Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Dependency Information" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Source Repository" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Mailing Lists" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Issue Tracking" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Continuous Integration" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Project Plugins" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Project License" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Project Team" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Project Summary" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Dependencies" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[CHECKSTYLE] Parsing file /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MavenProject2/test/target/checkstyle-result.xml
[CHECKSTYLE] Successfully parsed file /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MavenProject2/test/target/checkstyle-result.xml of module test with 1 unique warning and 0 duplicates.
[CHECKSTYLE] Computing warning deltas based on reference build #226
[JENKINS] Archiving site from /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MavenProject2/test/target/site to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MavenProject2/site
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ test ---
[INFO] Deleting /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MavenProject2/test/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ test ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MavenProject2/test/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ test ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MavenProject2/test/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ test ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MavenProject2/test/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ test ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MavenProject2/test/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ test ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MavenProject2/test/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running test.test.AppTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.052 sec

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[JENKINS] Recording test results
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ test ---
[INFO] Building jar: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MavenProject2/test/target/test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ test ---
[INFO] Installing /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MavenProject2/test/target/test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/test/test/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MavenProject2/test/pom.xml to /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/test/test/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check (default-cli) @ test ---
[INFO] There is 1 error reported by Checkstyle 6.11.2 with https://dustplanet.de/checkstyle.xml ruleset.
[ERROR] src/main/java/test/test/App.java:[11,43] (whitespace) WhitespaceAround: '{' is not preceded with whitespace.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 36.200 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-08-17T17:47:53+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 44M/106M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check (default-cli) on project test: You have 1 Checkstyle violation. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MavenProject2/test/pom.xml to test/test/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MavenProject2/test/target/test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to test/test/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Not sending mail to unregistered user rebmann@fzi.de
An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored.
channel stopped
[ANALYSIS-COLLECTOR] Computing warning deltas based on reference build #226
Not sending mail to unregistered user rebmann@fzi.de
An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored.
Finished: FAILURE
```

Does someone have any idea what I did wrong?

**EDIT 1** 
Ok i now know, that the checkstyle plugin in the build sequence doesn't work correctly becouse i get this warnings now.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugin:maven-checkstyle-plugin:jar:2.17 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugin:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugin:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugin:maven-checkstyle-plugin:jar:2.17 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building test 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugin:maven-checkstyle-plugin:jar:2.17 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugin:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugin:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugin:maven-checkstyle-plugin:jar:2.17 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
```

They only occur if i put the checkstyle plugin in the build sequence, the checkstyle plugin in the report sequence works correctly. How can i solve this warnings?

**EDIT 2**

ok the problem was that i forgot a "s" after plugin in `<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin</groupId>`. The plugin still dont get executed, but i now mark the build as unstable or failure over the checkstyle plugin in jenkins. I should have done this probibly the first way nevertheless ty for help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you like to achieve but your build process breaks cause you have an checkstyle error: `[ERROR] src/main/java/test/test/App.java:[11,43] (whitespace) WhitespaceAround: '{' is not preceded with whitespace....`.. ?

Comment: i want to achieve that the build process fails if a checkstile error occurs , but also that my checkstyle tend graph as well as the analysis report of jenkins get updated correctly. Right now i could only achieve that either the build process breaks or the tend graph got updated correctly, but not both together. Sorry if it's hard to understand me, im new too jenkins and maven, and my english isnt the best too.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `maven-checkstyle-plugin` reporting plugin into your `pom.xml`, you can use below plugin :

```
<project>
  ...
   <reporting>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.17</version>
          <reportSets>
            <reportSet>
              <reports>
                <report>checkstyle</report>
              </reports>
            </reportSet>
          </reportSets>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </reporting>
  ...
</project>
```

for more you can refer below link :

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/usage.html

Comment: mhm i already did that in the pom.xml above. The problem is not that the report doesn't get created, the problem is that the analysis report and graph trend of jenkins don't get updated the right way if the build process breaks and it seems like the checkstyle plugin in the <build></build> section doesn't work correctly.